# phantom image / li margin on firefox

Tags: html, css

Im currently getting a 4px margin on li elements with an image (image is highlighted) like so:

[image]

But this only appears in Fire-fox, in chrome there is no margin. But I have everything zeroed out in the CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

/* ------------- HEADER -------------- */

header{ 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 140px 0 #B0B0B0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 140px 0 #B0B0B0;
    position: relative;
}

header ul{
    text-indent:0;
}

header li{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

header li:first-child{
    width: 300px;
    color: black;
}

li.notices{ 
    background: #d80404; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d80404 0%, #c90a0a 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#d80404), color-stop(100%,#c90a0a)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d80404 0%,#c90a0a 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d80404 0%,#c90a0a 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d80404 0%,#c90a0a 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d80404 0%,#c90a0a 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d80404', endColorstr='#c90a0a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

What could be causing this?

http://jsfiddle.net/KJjVZ/

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="/core/css/img/ind.png" /></li
            ><li class="notices">
                <img src="/core/css/img/notices2.png" /></li
            ><li class="sessions">
                <img src="/core/css/img/sessions2.png" />
            </li
            ><li class="forum">
                <img src="/core/css/img/forums2.png" /></li
            ><li class="voting">
                    <img src="/core/css/img/voting2.png" /></li
            ><li class="support">
                <img src="/core/css/img/support2.png" /></li
            ><li class="login" role="login">
                <img src="/core/css/img/notices2.png" />
            </li>                   
           </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

(needed for drop down purposes)

Comment: Seeing your HTML would help. As would a jsFiddle.net example.

Comment: Only block elements have no implicit margin. Try that.

Comment: No problem with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KJjVZ/1/ (using the same image N times and the background that works for all items). Fx 29 and recent Chrome

Answer (score 1):

`inline-block` elements have a spacing effect between them in most browsers..

See [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Relevant Info:

> Here's the deal: a series of inline-block elements formatted like you normally format HTML will have spaces in between them.

**Solution 1**: Remove the spaces

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li
  ><li>two</li
  ><li>three</li>
</ul>
```

**Solution 2**: Negative margin

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

Comment: Thats not it, I've stopped that by doing keeping the li open till the next line.

Comment: It's not `4px`. It's `.25em`. But not always. Every browser has a different system.

Comment: I've put the relevant information to why this happens, and two different ways to solve it.

Comment: I've updated the post to show the HTML how i have it, so its already stopping the spacing.

Comment: No, i already had that before the post, And this spacing is inside the Li element.

Comment: Make a JSFiddle, so we can easily fix this.

Comment: @TristanCunningham Your fiddle has broken images, and when I test this on Firefox, there is no extra spacing.

Comment: @rudie Yahoo! used .31em https://github.com/yui/pure/issues/41/ for its Pure CSS framework (and encountered many problems due to their extensive support of browsers and cases and switched to flexbox for IE10+ though may still use this for IE9-, I didn't check for many months...) EDIT: removing whitespace from HTML code is always the best option when possible

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is `font-size: 0`:

```
body { font-size: 14px; }
ul { font-size: 0; }
li { font-size: 14px; }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/NuwPR/

The downside, which I think is significant, is repeating the font-size. You might not know the exact font-size of every `LI`, so you might be specifying a lot of cases. `font-size: inherit` unfortunately uses the `0`.